# Как можно редактировать или удалять сообщения без указания их id на странице?

Tags: javascript, php, чат

Есть чат на чистом PHP и Js. У каждого сообщения в атрибутах указан id сообщения из бд. По нему я редактирую или удаляю сообщения. На сервер отправляется id сообщения. На сервере убеждаюсь, что это владелец сообщения, и что-то с ним делаю. Как можно это сделать без указания id сообщения на странице?

Comment: А сам-то как себе представляешь это? Как твоё сообщение должно идентифицироваться, не имея идентификатора?

Comment: Открыл я чат одного из сайтов, и в HTML - коде нет каких-либо идентификаторов сообщения

Comment: @Aladser HTML - это то, что используется для отображения данных и получения данных от клиента. Там и не должно быть никаких идентификаторов

Comment: Тогда как мне распознавать сообщение, которое я хочу удалить?

Comment: @Aladser без идентификаторов - вряд ли возможно. Просто на странице, которую ты открыл, данные храняться где-нибудь в переменной js, а потом на основе этого массива просто отрисовывается html.  При клике на строчку, js получает индекс строки (условно), в своём массиве по этому индексу берёт идентификатор и отправляет его на бэк

Comment: @Aladser ну так ты и не выводи нигде идентификатор на странице

Comment: безопасно хранить эти id в JS?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, **исходная** проблема-то? С чего вдруг ударило в голову делать "без указания id сообщения на странице"?

Comment: `Открыл я чат одного из сайтов, и в HTML - коде нет каких-либо идентификаторов сообщения` 1. то что вы их не нашли, еще не гарантирует их отсутствия. 2. а если они и отсутствуют, вы хорошо проверили тот чат? и уверены что функционал там не хуже вашего? :-/ **`безопасно хранить эти id в JS?`** ах вот в чем дело... ну... без них сервак будет вынужден гадать на кофейной гуще какое именно сообщение редактируется, что гхм... еще менее безопасно чем иды в js :3 p.s. главное экранируйте прилетающий на бэк `messageId` перед его вставкой в SQL и все будет нормально.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но скорее всего такое можно реализовать с помощью Vue.js.

Answer (score -1):

Это можно сделать с помощью формы, содержащей **input type=hidden**, у которого через **value** можно будет передавать **id** сообщения, не показывая его на странице. На примере только удаления кнопкой **удалить** правее каждого сообщения можно отправлять данные из этой формы и с помощью PHP удалять из БД сообщение с **id**, которое было передано. Если кроме удаления нужны другие действия - чуть сложнее, тогда можно, на пример, на против сообщения отмечать **checkbox**, а внизу из списка выбрать нужное действие над отмеченными сообщениями.

Comment: "Как можно это сделать **без указания id сообщения на странице**?"

Comment: Т. е., нужен код, - чуть по-позже.

Comment: Код не нужен потому что: а) без указания id будет невозможно, b) это все равно не имеет смысла

Comment: Можете столбик **id** в БД назвать не обязательно id, а ка-то по-другому, но он должен содержать неповторяющиеся значения, иначе не за что будет зацепиться, чтобы эдэнтихвыцыровать нужную для удаления строку. Если будет 2 одинаковых значения, то придётся удалить сразу две строки. Даже в **PHPMyAdmin**е по этой причине в оной ситуации не отображаются кнопки для редактирования строк.

Comment: При чем здесь название столбика?